# Simpleadapter (JSON with sub items)

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development, and I'm trying for several days to make my app work but with no success.
I'm using `AsyncTask` and `SimpleAdapter`, it returns the data however my `JSON` has sub items. It's a `JSON` of comments where sometimes in a comment has the answers of that comment. But I have no idea if I do a `listView` inside a `listView`. I'm really lost, I searched a lot and I did not find anything about my problem.

Follow the **JSON**:

```
{
COMENTARIOS: [
{
    comentarios_id: "1053939",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "ludi",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "186.212.2.226",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 09:34:00",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "67",
    naogostei: "143",
    resp: [ ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1053943",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Andre",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "187.120.224.30",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 09:45:01",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "236",
    naogostei: "114",
    resp: [
    {
        comentarios_id: "1053945",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1053943",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "Usuário",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "187.39.180.166",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 09:51:54",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "143",
        naogostei: "219",
        resp: [ ]
    },
    {
        comentarios_id: "1053987",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1053943",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "Roberto, o Legítimo",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "177.6.152.156",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 11:39:52",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "82",
        naogostei: "124",
        resp: [ ]
    },
    {
        comentarios_id: "1054030",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1053943",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "xumbinho",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "186.232.178.237",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 13:19:51",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "69",
        naogostei: "116",
        resp: [ ]
    }
    ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1053964",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Celso",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "177.97.174.169",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 10:38:06",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "41",
    naogostei: "116",
    resp: [ ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1054061",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Usuário",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "181.223.181.27",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 14:23:10",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "60",
    naogostei: "15",
    resp: [
    {
        comentarios_id: "1054173",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1054061",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "bob",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "92.59.121.38",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 17:19:32",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "5",
        naogostei: "106",
        resp: [ ]
    },
    {
        comentarios_id: "1054485",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1054061",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "Usuário",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "187.55.120.227",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-04 10:24:56",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "0",
        naogostei: "0",
        resp: [ ]
    }
    ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1054304",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Jorge",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "189.74.113.127",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 21:00:03",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "1",
    naogostei: "0",
    resp: [ ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1054382",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Pé na cova",
    email: "email@email.com",
    ip: "168.194.160.137",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 23:45:29",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "1",
    naogostei: "0",
    resp: [ ]
}
]
}
```

In AsyncTask inside the `protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)` I make the JSON call this way:

```
    JSONArray comentarios = jsonObj.getJSONArray("COMENTARIOS");
    for (int i = 0; i < comentarios.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = comentarios.getJSONObject(i);
      String nome = c.getString("nome");
      String comentario = c.getString("comentario");

      HashMap<String, String> comentariotxt = new HashMap<>();

      comentariotxt.put("nome", nome);
      comentariotxt.put("comentario", comentario);

      JSONArray resp = c.getJSONArray("resp");
      if(resp.length() > 0){
          for (int j = 0; j < resp.length(); j++){
              JSONObject d = resp.getJSONObject(j);
              String respostaNome = d.getString("nome");
              String respostaComentario = d.getString("comentario");
              Log.d("respostaNome",respostaNome);

              HashMap<String, String> respostatxt = new HashMap<>();
              respostatxt.put("respostaNome", respostaNome);
              respostatxt.put("respostaComentario", respostaComentario);
              comentarioList.add(respostatxt);
          }
      }
      comentarioList.add(comentariotxt);
  }
```

But here it already messes everything up. Well, I need two things. Let them bring the comment and the answers in order and the appearance of the balloon responses will be different from the comment balloon. At the moment I'm only doing a listview of the comments, but I'm also not sure if I need another listview for the answers. I mean ... I'm very lost! Someone help me?

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: show your right json. This json is invalid as i am trying it on JSON Validator.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify your **json** with single object.

Please check the below code to parse this **json**:

```
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject("{\n" +
                "\t\"COMENTARIOS\": [{\n" +
                "\t\t\"comentarios_id\": \"1053939\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"noticias_id\": \"284901\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"duelos_id\": \"0\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"respostas_id\": \"0\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"videos_id\": \"0\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"nome\": \"ludi\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"email\": \"email@email.com.br\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"ip\": \"186.212.2.226\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"comentario\": \"COMENTÁRIO\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"data_cadastro\": \"2018-04-03 09:34:00\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"status\": \"3\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"gostei\": \"67\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"naogostei\": \"143\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"resp\": []\n" +
                "\t}]\n" +
                "}");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("COMENTARIOS");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String comentarios_id = jsonObject.get("noticias_id").toString();
            System.out.println("----comentarios_id---" + comentarios_id);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("----comentarios_id---exc--" + e);
    }
```

`Note:` In json object where i am passing static json, you need to pass your own string where all the json is stored.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply!
But my problem is to display this for the layout. I do not know how in the listview to show the comments and below the comments that have answers display the answers of the comment.